# Application returns error in autofill function on textbox_Leave(); using c#

Tags: c#

In my application I store customers of a company. The user will be able to add customer number, name, address etc. These informations are stored in an xml file. And on the first tab of tabControl the user can type in the customer number in a textbox and then it autofills the surname and forename. And if the customer number is not available it appears a message box.

Well that sounds okay. But I got an issue with Visual Studio. I got this code:

```
private void txtKNrNew_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path + "\\save.xml");
    int CustNos;

    if (Int32.TryParse(txtKNrNew.Text, out CustNos))
    {
        var xmlNodeExist = "Buchhaltung/Customers/CustNo";
        var existingCustNo = xdoc.XPathSelectElements(xmlNodeExist).FirstOrDefault(x => (int)x == CustNos);

        if (existingCustNo == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Diese Kundennummer ist nicht vorhanden!", "Kundennummer nicht vorhanden", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(path + "\\save.xml");

        var CustNoExist = String.Format("//Customers[CustNo/text() = {0}]/", CustNos);

        var SurnameNode = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(CustNoExist + "Surname");
        var ForenameNode = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(CustNoExist + "Forename");
        string surname = SurnameNode[0].InnerText;
        string forename = ForenameNode[0].InnerText;

        if (CustNoExist != null)
        {
            txtSurnameNew.Text = surname;
            txtForenameNew.Text = forename;
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("aaaaaaaaaaa");
        }
    }
}
```

If I type in a customer number which does not exist it appears a messagebox to say that this customer number is not defined. But then Visual Studio interrupt the application and return an error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

If someone could give me a hint why this happen I'd be very pleased.

Comment: You need a return statement after showing the message box.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You mean I have to return `existingCustNo` right after the MessageBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @adrianbanks said in the comments, you need to return, exit, stop processing, etc. after you find that the customer number does not exist.

To do that you `return` out of the method like so:

```cs
if (existingCustNo == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Diese Kundennummer ist nicht vorhanden!", "Kundennummer nicht vorhanden", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Ah I just have to do `return;`. I searched in my code what I have to return. Normally I have to return an object or am I wrong or misunderstood it? For example `return testString;`. Or is this just in JavaScript? I'm a bit confused now :)

Comment: `return;` by itself immediately exits the method without executing the rest of the code that comes after it.  You are not in a function, so you don't need to return an object.